# YCombinator not working in Swift

Tags: swift, y-combinator

I am trying to create a lambda function as such to get a factorial function but this throws a segmentation fault and errors out. How do I get this working in Swift. Please look at this video for reference on what I am trying to do http://www.confreaks.com/videos/1287-rubyconf2012-y-not-adventures-in-functional-programming

```
typealias f = () -> ()
typealias g = (Int) -> (Int)
typealias F = Any -> g

let y = { (gen: Any) -> g in
    (gen as F)(gen)
}
let fact = y({ (gen: Any) -> g in
    { (n: Int) -> Int in
        if n == 0 {
            return 1
        } else {
            return n * (gen as F)(gen)(n - 1)
        }
    }
})

fact(10)
```

Comment: It now works in the latest beta.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [great post by xiliangchen](http://xiliangchen.wordpress.com/2014/08/04/recursive-closure-and-y-combinator-in-swift/) that walks through creating a Y-combinator in Swift. (Technically, this isn't a Y-*combinator*, since it is explicitly recursive, but it largely does what you want.) Here's an example of that Y function (stripped of its generic specification for clarity):

```
typealias G = Int -> Int

func Y (f: G -> G) -> G {
    return {
        (i: Int) -> Int in
        f(Y(f))(i)
    }
}

let factorial = Y { (f: G) -> G in
    { (n: Int) -> Int in
        if n == 0 {
            return 1
        } else {
            return n * f(n - 1)
        }
    }
}

factorial(5)        // 120
```

For more on Y-combinators, you can look at this [terrific (long) piece by Mike Vanier](http://mvanier.livejournal.com/2897.html).

(*Note:* Using `Any` is kind of a mess -- I'd recommend steering clear of it whenever you can, especially since you don't need it in this case.)

Comment: Could you update this to modern Swift 4.1?  This might sound silly, but I genuinely can't figure out how to get it to compile

Comment: See my answer, sorry for arriving late :-) .  It now compiles to modern Swift 5.7

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a real (without explicit recursion) Y combinator using a recursive type, without any unsafe tricks (credits to [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Y_combinator)):

```
struct RecursiveFunc<F> {
  let o : RecursiveFunc<F> -> F
}

func Y<A, B>(f: (A -> B) -> A -> B) -> A -> B {
  let r = RecursiveFunc<A -> B> { w in f { w.o(w)($0) } }
  return r.o(r)
}

let factorial = Y { (f: Int -> Int) -> Int -> Int in
  { $0 <= 1 ? 1 : $0 * f($0-1) }
}
println(factorial(10))
```

<s>`Any` doesn't really help because [`Any` cannot represent function types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH22-XID_503).</s>

**Update:** Starting in Xcode 6.1 beta 3, `Any` can represent function types, and your code compiles and works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This is an implementation in modern Swift that actually compiles under Swift 5.7. It has the proper modern closure syntax and declares as escaping the escaping closures.

```swift
import Foundation

struct RecursiveFunc<T> {
    let o : (RecursiveFunc<T>) -> T
}

func Y<A, B>(f: @escaping (@escaping (A)  -> B)  -> (A) -> B) -> (A) -> B {
    let r = RecursiveFunc<(A) -> B> {  w in f { w.o(w)($0) } }
  return r.o(r)
}

let fac = Y { (f: @escaping (Int) -> Int) in
  { $0 <= 1 ? 1 : $0 * f($0-1) }
}

func fact (_ n: Int) -> Int {
    if n == 0 { return 1 }
    else { return n * fact (n-1) }
}


print (fact(19))
print (fac (19))
```

NB: code pasted from a PlayGround